# Multilingual Jade templates?

Tags: json, node.js, gulp, pug

I'm using the Jade template engine with gulp, [gulp-jade](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jade) and [gulp-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-data) to build a very basic one-page website in two languages. The result should be static HTML documents with no further server-side or client-side processing. Is it possible to load website content from a JSON file depending on a language I define in my `index.jade`, and what would be the best way to go about doing this?

My current attempt causes an error:

**gulpfile.js:**

```js
gulp.task('views', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/**/*.jade')
    .pipe($.data(function(file) {
      return require('./app/data/text.json'); // load language file
    }))
    .pipe($.jade({pretty: true, basedir: 'app/'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp'));
});
```

**text.json:**

```json
{
  "de": {
    "foo": "deutsch"
  },

  "en": {
    "foo": "english"
  }
}
```

**index_en.jade:**

```jade
extends /_layouts/default.jade

var lang = "en"

block content

    h1 #{lang.foo} // load text from json
```

This results in the following error when I run gulp:

```
Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined
```

I don't mind splitting up the JSON into different files per language if that makes things easier, but I have no idea how I would include the appropriate file from within `index_en.jade`.

**Some context:**

I should note that I'm extending a default layout file (`default.jade`), which itself includes a bunch of things like `header.jade` and `footer.jade` to keep the template system as DRY as possible. Those files would need to be multilingual as well, which is why I would like to define `lang="en"` in my `index_en.jade`, `lang="de"` in `index_de.jade`, and just have that propagate to all of the other partials without having to duplicate those as well (e.g. no `header_de.jade` or such).

I'm also merging these features back into my [yeoman generator](https://github.com/jdahdah/generator-gulp-dahdah), so I would like to find a system where I can avoid having to adjust `gulpfile.js` if I were to add another language later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error lies in `#{lang.foo}`. You've set lang to a string and that doesn't have a foo on it… If you set lang to the actual object that you're loading (en or de in this case), it works fine:

```
extends /_layouts/default.jade

block content

    - var lang = en

    h1 #{lang.foo} // load text from json
```

Note the missing quotation marks.

Edit: Variable declaration needs to be inside block (sometimes).

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Both the string and block scope were a problem.