# How to load json data with jade?

Tags: javascript, html, json, pug

I read a way to implement json data in jade with the following code: h1 = t('pages.index.headline')
But it doesn't work. All I get is this line as normal text or if I write "h1= t(..." instead of "h1 = t(..." my precompiler (Prepros) says "t is not a function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This same thing got me strugglin some time ago, this posts help me a lot:

[multilingual jade templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090945/multilingual-jade-templates)

Comment: btw. I also found some days ago the syntax h1= t('pages.index.headline). Do you know how to use it? If I implement this syntax my precompiler just says "t is not a function".

Comment: Are you sure it's a "t" ? Take a look at this page, it also helped me a lot using vars and other notations. http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#variables

Comment: wow, that looks good, ty.
And yes, its = t()
The structure was: 
json file
`page {
 index {
  title: "hello"
 }
}`

and in jade: 

`h1.className= t('pages.index.title')`

Comment: The solution of the version I found with the t-function is based on i18next node package. Very useful, check it out.